# Truly dynamic C# objects - pivoting data with <n> number of properties (and dynamic property names)

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, expandoobject

There HAS to be an elegant solution to this problem that I am missing.  What I'm looking for *seems* exceedingly simple, yet I have not yet figured out a way to accomplish this.

I have the following object:

```
internal class OverrideValue
{
    public int RID { get; set; }
    public int PID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

A given RID can have multiple PID/value combinations.  I need to return a dynamically created (and named) list back to the client with JSON.  So, given the following:

```
var overrideList = new List<OverrideValue>()
{
    new OverrideValue() {RID = 1, PID = 1, Value = "200"},
    new OverrideValue() {RID = 1, PID = 2, Value = "250"},
    new OverrideValue() {RID = 2, PID = 1, Value = "200"},
    new OverrideValue() {RID = 2, PID = 3, Value = "300"},
    new OverrideValue() {RID = 2, PID = 4, Value = "255"}
};
```

I need to return an object like this:

```
{ "overrides":[
    { "RID":1, "PID_1":"200", "PID_2":"250" },
    { "RID":2, "PID_1":"200", "PID_3":"300", "PID_4":"255" }
]}
```

If my database returns a PID of 400,000, I need the object to contain a property called "**PID_4000000**" with an associated value.

I realize that type-safety is a huge part of C#, but it seems ridiculous for me to have to construct JSON manually for this situation.  It seems like there should be a built-in method for me to be able to create a dynamic object.  I have tried working with the ExpandoObject(), but all that has managed to give me is a list of Dictionary() key/value pairs, which is worthless - when serialized, the properties are "key" and "value".

What this boils down to is that I am using a grid which will only bind to a flat (1-dimensional) JSON datasource, and I need to construct the grid with whatever data happens to come my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky, but should give you enough to go on and tailor to your needs. It uses Linq to group the values and dictionaries to store the grouped items.

First we need a wrapper class to match your output properly:

```
public class Output
{
    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, int>> Overrides { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can group your data:

```
//Grou pand aggregate the data
var results = overrideList
    .GroupBy(l => l.RID)
    .Select(l =>
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dictionary.Add("RID", l.Key);
        foreach (var pidValue in l)
        {
            dictionary.Add($"PID_{pidValue.PID}", int.Parse(pidValue.Value));
        }
        return dictionary;
    });

//Throw the data into our output class
var output = new Output
{
    Overrides = results
};

//Convert to JSON
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
```

This gives output something like this:

```
{"Overrides":[
    {"RID":1,"PID_1":200,"PID_2":250},
    {"RID":2,"PID_1":200,"PID_3":300,"PID_4":255}
]}
```

Comment: This actually ended up working for me.  I am not sure where I was going wrong, but originally when I serialized the List<Dictionary<string, int>> object, I was getting something like this:

`{"Overrides":[
    {"Key":"PID_1", "Value":200"}, [...] 
]}`

I was trying a lot of different methods, and somehow, it now serializes correctly.  I am not certain what changed.

Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

seeing how you are saving your data, this json representation is not the default one, as you combine multiple list entries into 1 single combined entry.

I recommend using a Jsom serialiser that allows you to define which attributes/functions should be parsed. Then implement a function that returns a list of dictionaries that combines the list entries into the corresponding combined ones. Then let the serialiser serialise the output of that function and you are done.

You can use this class to do so: [Json.NET JSONConvertor](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm)